# Tricky WPF binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, windows-phone-7, listbox, binding

I'm unable to do a simple but yet tricky WPF binding in Silverlight 4 (WP7 development)

I have the following code:

```
Class People{
    public string firstname;
    public string lastname;
}

Class DataSource{
    public static List<People> people; // consider this as a list filled with objects already
}
```

I'm trying to put the list of people into a ListBox, here's the xaml I've tried:

```
            <ListBox x:Name="peoplelistbox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource.people}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                      <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding firstname}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding lastname}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                      </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

But unfortunately my listbox remains empty. What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you in advance :)

Cheers,
Miloud B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly you are using fields, where you should use `public` property (i.e. people, firstname and lastname). Convert `people` to a public property, like this:

```
public static List<People> people { get; set; }
```

Then, you need to bind the `ItemsSource` using `x:Static` markup, like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="peoplelistbox" Margin="0,0,-12,0">
   <ListBox.ItemsSource>
      <Binding Source="{x:Static local:DataSource.people}"/>
   <ListBox.ItemsSource/>
   ...
```

PS: `local` is the xml namespace pointing to your `DataSource` class's namespace. Also, your class too needs to be a public class.

**EDIT:**
For WP7, you need to declare the instance of the class in the resources and then you can use `Path` to point to the source. Like this:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <local:DataSource x:Key="dataSource"/>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
...
<ListBox x:Name="peoplelistbox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataSource}, Path=people}">
```

PS: Again, your class needs to be public and must have a default constructor.

**EDIT:**
Here is a example which is working perfectly on my system. Check and see where are you making the mistake:

```
namespace WindowsPhoneApplication1
{
    public class People
    {
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public string lastname { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataSource
    {
        public static List<People> people { get; set; }

        public DataSource() { }

        static DataSource()
        {
            people = new List<People> {new People {firstname = "Foo", lastname = "Bar"}};
        }
    }

    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml (only the relevant portions):

```
...
...
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WindowsPhoneApplication1"
...
...
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <local:DataSource x:Key="dataSource"/>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
...
...
<ListBox x:Name="peoplelistbox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataSource}, Path=people}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding firstname}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding lastname}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: It's ok but remember to add `xmlns:my="clr-namespace:datasourcenamespace"` and then to fix binding with `<Binding Source="{x:Static my:DataSource.People}" />`.
Fix also ItemsSource changing it into `ListBox.ItemsSource`.

Comment: Thanks as-cii. Just typed all from memory. Corrected.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But it doesn't work for SV4. I forgot to mention that I was working on WP7.

Comment: @Yogesh thank you very much. In fact, I don't have the Window namespace, I've also tried using <PhoneApplicationPage but it doesn't have the Resources property.. Is that normal?

Comment: Oops. Corrected yet again. :P

Comment: @Yogesh I got it **but** it says: "Cannot create an instance of DataSource" weird isn't it ?

Comment: Check if your class is public. Secondly check if your class has a default constructor (default = parameterless).

Comment: Yogesh I fixed this ! I was missing a default non-static and parameterless constructor. 
Edit: Oupse ! :P. Thank you

Comment: @Yogesh I did exactly everything you said, no compile errors nor warnings **but** the binding is still not done. I checked that my list is correctly filled with data and don't know how to debug this stuff. Any other hints ? :) Thx in advance

Comment: Are you sure that the data is filled in the property? Make an static constructor too and make sure in the constructor that you fill up some random data into people for checking.

Comment: Data is actually filled after starting, I query a web service which successfully returns back list of objects. I'm a 100% sure data is filled in correctly...

Comment: In that case, either implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`.

Comment: ObservableCollection doesn't work on WP7 when consuming WCF ws.
INotifyPropertyChanged ? Gonna read about it and try it.
Thank you ;)

Comment: @Yogesh I can't believe it... Just realized that I do already implement INotifyPropertyChanged...

Comment: I am posting a perfectly working example in my edit. See if you spot the difference. BTW, are your firstname and lastname fields or public properties? Do check.

Comment: Yogesh I guarantee at 100% that I've exactly the same thing as you do. And yes my properties are public too I just double checked.
Do you think the problem might be the fact that I have List<T> rather than ObservableCollection<T> ? Because when the app starts, my people list is empty, then it gets filled later when the WCF returns data

Comment: Haha. Can't figure. See my edit. Working perfectly on my system. Also do check that is your listbox visible and big enough.

Comment: @Yogesh shoot me ! hurt me ! kill me !... It's indeed due to List<T> that doesn't seem to be observable, if I put objects into the list in the constructor the binding works... I have to convert my lists to ObservableCollection... it's unfortunate that it doesn't work with WCF... Man thank you very much, you helped me so much

Answer (score 1):

1.`FirstName` and `LastName` need to be public properties with at least getters.
2.Your list should also be a public property unless you explicitly set the `DataContext` of your Window
3.Need to either set the `DataContext` or reference the source otherwise.
4.You cannot bind to static properties like that, use `{x:Static ...}`.
5.This is not a tricky binding -.-

As devdigital said you might want to implement those interfaces as well.

Comment: This isn't a tricky binding but all stuff you've mentioned doesn't solve the problem ;). Thank you for the hints

Cheers

Comment: Well, just about everything one could do wrong in a binding was wrong with yours, so it is easy to miss something. I think you should have read up on the basics of binding before asking this question...

Comment: Don't take this as a personal attack, I was just messing with you... and you're totally right I should have been read the basics before asking but I had absolutely no time, I had a project at work and this binding is a tiny part of it that's why I wanted to leverage my time to finish the whole thing and try to find a solution to the binding here on stackoverflow. I plan to read about this because it's very important though.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can only bind to properties, so change your public fields to properties.

Also, if you want your UI to update on programmatic changes to your people instances, then implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your People type (really that type should be called Person).

If you want your UI to update when items are added/removed from your DataSource people collection, then use `ObservableCollection<T>` rather than `List<T>`.

Comment: Hi devdigital. Thanks for the hints !
- properties fields: done
- INotifyPropertyChanged: Implemented
- Can't use ObservableCollection<T> with WP7 & WCF :(